# connect to shell terminal of other container in a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-security

When I define multiple containers in a pod/pod template like one container running `agent` and another `php-fpm`, how can they access each other? I need the `agent container` to connect to `php-fpm` by shell and need to execute few steps interactively through `agent container`.

Based on my understanding, we can package `kubectl` into the `agent container` and use `kubectl exec -it <container id> sh` to connect to the container. But I don't want `Agent container` to have more privilege than to connect to the target container with is `php-fpm`.

Is there a better way for `agent container` to connect to `php-fpm` by a shell and execute commands interactively?

Also, I wasn't successful in running `kubectl` from a container when using `minikube` due to following errors

```
docker run -it -v ~/.kube:/root/.kube lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl get nodes
Error in configuration:
* unable to read client-cert /Users/user/.minikube/apiserver.crt for minikube due to open /Users/user/.minikube/apiserver.crt: no such file or directory
* unable to read client-key /Users/user/.minikube/apiserver.key for minikube due to open /Users/user/.minikube/apiserver.key: no such file or directory
* unable to read certificate-authority /Users/user/.minikube/ca.crt for minikube due to open /Users/user/.minikube/ca.crt: no such file or directory
```

Comment: _Is there a better way for agent container to connect to php-fpm by a shell and execute commands interactively?_ it is very hard to answer that question without knowing what you are _attempting_ to do; what are you attempting to do with these shell commands?

Comment: _But I don't want Agent container to have more privilege than to connect to the target container with is php-fpm_ then you should give up on your `kubectl exec` approach, because without doing some very, very serious work with RBAC, the Pod will be able to do anything that it wishes from inside the cluster

Answer (score 0):

> docker run -it -v ~/.kube:/root/.kube lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl get nodes

1. First off, every Pod within a k8s cluster has its own k8s credentials provided by `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`, and thus there is absolutely no need to attempt to volume mount your home directory into a docker container
2. The reason you are getting the error about `client-cert` is because the contents of `~/.kube` are merely *strings* that point to the externally defined ssl key, ssl certificate, and ssl CA certificate defined inside `~/.kube/config` -- but I won't speak to fixing that problem further since there is no good reason to be using that approach

Comment: Do you think `kubectl proxy` is better approach to use to access kubernetes api?